# how to rise hover event after some millisecond?

Tags: jquery

i create a menu and i show and hide submenu on jquery via hover event like following code

is any way, submenu show or hide after some milisecond mouse stay over them?

```
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').show(600);

        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').fadeOut(400);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out hoverintent
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer in the handlerIn function for `hover()`.  Clear the timer in handlerOut.

```
var timeoutId = { };

function show(id) {
    $("#"+id).find('ul:first').show(600);
    timeoutId[id]= null;
}

function init() {
      $("#nav > li").hover(
          function(){
              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              timeoutId[id]= setTimeout(function(){show(id);}, 800);
          },
          function(){
              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              if (typeof timeoutId[id] != "undefined" && timeoutId[id]!=null) {
                  clearTimeout(timeoutId[id]);
                  timeoutId[id]= null;
              }
              $(this).find('ul:first').fadeOut(400);
          }
      );
  }

  $(document).ready(init);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise version than [Cheeso's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398042/how-to-rise-hover-event-after-some-milisecond/2398291#2398291):

```
$(function() {
    $("#Trigger").hover(
        function() {
            $("#Target").delay(800).fadeIn(0);
        },
        function() {
            $("#Target").clearQueue().fadeOut(400);
        }
    );
});
```

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will cause `#Target` not to fade in for 800ms. When you hover out (regardless if it's while `#Target` is fully displayed or waiting to be displayed due to `delay`), [`clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) is called. If it happens during those 800ms, `delay` and `fadeIn` are cleared from the queue. Otherwise the queue will already be empty. In either case, `#Target` is faded out immediately.

(Note that you need to use `fadeIn(0)` instead of `show` because `show` isn't something that goes on the fx queue and `delay` will therefore have no effect.)

And if you also want to delay the `fadeOut`, `delay` needs to go after `clearQueue`, not before it.

**Update**

I noticed that if, instead of `fadeIn(0)`, you use `fadeIn(500)`, but you hover out during those 500ms, then on subsequent hover overs, `#Target` will only fade in to the opacity that it was previously allowed to fade in to. Anybody know if this is intended behavior?